# PostgreSQL - Query optimization on SUM and LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm taking the month using `to_char()` which is common in two tables namely `Table1` and `Table2`.

But in Table2 I have both date and month.

Also I've created a index on Table1. If I write the same query only Table1 I get the results within 1000ms.

I'm taking sum of values and combining the results using left join.

Here's the query.

```
SELECT
    "month", -- Table2
    sum("value1"), -- Table2
    sum("value2") -- Table1
FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON
    Table2."month" = to_char(Table1.Date, 'Mon-yy')
WHERE Table2.Date BEtween '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-01'
GROUP BY "month"
```

EXPLAIN OF THE Query :

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=88133.61..3688425.12 rows=2 width=15)"
"  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=88133.61..2707006.48 rows=130855816 width=15)"
"        Merge Cond: (Table2.month = (to_char((Table1.date)::timestamp with time zone, 'Mon-yy'::text)))"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=8922.32..9056.34 rows=53609 width=11)"
"              Sort Key: Table2.month"
"              ->  Seq Scan on Table2(cost=0.00..3885.28 rows=53609 width=11)"
"                    Filter: ((date >= '2014-01-01'::date) AND (date   Materialize  (cost=79211.29..81652.22 rows=488186 width=8)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=79211.29..80431.75 rows=488186 width=8)"
"                    Sort Key: (to_char((Table1.date)::timestamp with time zone, 'Mon-yy'::text))"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on Table1(cost=0.00..19735.86 rows=488186 width=8)"
```

Currently I have about 500k rows in Table1.

Everyday I update the table with around 3 to 4k records to Table1.

The query just keeps running.

I get no results.

Can i anyone say me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you add your table definition and an explain of the query?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: I'm a newbie. Managed to get the EXPLAIN of the query. How will I get the table definition?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - When I run this EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS). Query doesn't stop at all. It keeps on running for about 5 mins.

Comment: Which indexes are defined on the tables? Do you have an index on `table2.date`?  How many rows from `table2` will be selected by the condition `between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-01'`? And why do you have a `month` column in `table2` if you already have a `date` column that apparently stores the full date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - As I'm a newbie. I didn't plan that much on creating a table. So I blindly added both date and month to make myself easier. And the rows returned will be 60-90 rows i.e., 1 row for 1 day will be counted. And there's no index in the Table2, it has about 100k rows. Index is only in the Table1 on the column `date`. That's the only index in Table1. Is my query correct by the way?

Answer (score 1):

For your query to run 'efficiently', you will need 2 indexes.
Judging by the explain, table2 needs an index on the date column.

`CREATE INDEX ON table2 using btree(date);`

table1 will need a computed index with the month name and day number e.g. "Apr-14".

`CREATE INDEX ON table1 using btree(to_char(date, 'Mon-yy'));`

[edit, as a_horse_with_no_name said this will not work because to_char is not immutable - you could get round this by writing your own immutable function, but really it would be much simpler if you just stored a date column!]

That said, text matching is slower than dates or numbers and if you want to order the information you will only get an alphabetical sort.

Comment: The second index cannot be created because `to_char()` isn't an immutable function. `to_char(date, 'Mon-yy')` on my computer might return something different than on your computer (because of localized month names).